# OpenLDAP server: chaining of SSL certificates (let's encrypt) does not work as expected

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, openldap, lets-encrypt

Okay, this is gonna be a long one, I fear. Please bear with me.

### setting

I have an OpenLDAP 2.4.50 server running on Alpine 3.12.1. It's serving LDAPS only with a let's encrypt staging certificate (at the moment, but prod environment will be no different, certificate-wise). Specifically it uses `cert.pem` referenced by `olcTLSCertificateFile` in `cn=config`. Everything works fine, I can connect and work with it using ApacheDirectoryStudio (acknowledging that I trust the host, though the cert seems smelly). Connecting with any OpenLDAP clients, such as `ldapsearch` or `ldapmodify`, needs a `TLS_CACERT`-entry in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` that consists of `cat intermediate.pem root.pem > rootchain.pem`. And this is where things get funny.

As those of you who have worked with let's encrypt know, let's encrypt (or rather certbot) usually provides us with the following:

- `privkey.pem` - the private key
- `cert.pem` - the server's certificate
- `chain.pem` - the intermediate certificate between out server certificate and the CA
- `fullchain.pem` - the chain form our server certificate to the root certificate without root, aka. `cat cert.pem chain.pem > fullchain.pem`

No `root.pem` and no `root-chain.pem`, the latter being `cat chain.pem root.pem > rootchain.pem`.

People throughout the webz state, that web browsers do some black magic if they don't get provided with the intermediate certificate but know of the root certificate and somehow retrieve the intermediate then, which I might be tempted to believe by own experience. These people say: for "normal" servers, just provide a certificate chain to the CA without the actual CA certificate as your certificate to your server software (e. g. [Get your certificate chain right](https://medium.com/@superseb/get-your-certificate-chain-right-4b117a9c0fce)). After having had a more thorough look into all this, this totally makes sense, as [rfc 4346, section 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.2) states

> *"certificate_list
>
> This is a sequence (chain) of X.509v3 certificates.  The sender's
> certificate must come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate must directly certify the one preceding it."*

According to this I should be able to provide `fullChain.pem` (which is `cat cert.pem chain.pem > fullchain.pem`) to `olcTLSCertificateFile` in `cn=config` and the [root certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/fakelerootx1.pem) to clients in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` as `TLS_CACERT` and every client should just run properly. Simply put, nope, they don't.

#### fun fact

`openssl verify -CAfile root.pem somechain.pem` only succeeds, if `somechain.pem` is `cat chain.pem cert.pem > somechain.pem` which should be wrong according to the rfc... ?!

#### conclusion

So to conclude all this:

- Is providing a chained PEM of the form `cat server.pem intermediate_lowest.pem intermediat_mid.pem intermediate-highest.pem` as a server certificate the correct way?
- If so or if not, how am I doing this correctly with OpenLDAP?

---

As requested in the comments, here comes the output of `openssl s_client -connect` for both, with root certificate only and with a chain of intermediate certificate followed by the root certificate. At the time of the requests, `slapd` is configured to use `fullchain.pem` aka. `cert.pem` followed by `chain.pem`.

- root certificate only
  `openssl s_client -showcerts -CAfile fakelerootx1.pem -connect directory.domain.tld:636 < /dev/null > with-rootcert.log 2>&1`

```
depth=0 CN = *.domain.tld
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.domain.tld
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.domain.tld
   i:CN = Fake LE Intermediate X1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[ cert data removed, it is the single cert.pem from lets encrypt ]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN = *.domain.tld

issuer=CN = Fake LE Intermediate X1

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1899 bytes and written 401 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
DONE
```

- chain made of intermediate followed by root
  `openssl s_client -showcerts -CAfile fakerootchain.pem -connect directory.domain.tld:636 < /dev/null > with-root_and_intermediate_cert.log 2>&1`

```
depth=2 CN = Fake LE Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 CN = Fake LE Intermediate X1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.domain.tld
verify return:1
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.domain.tld
   i:CN = Fake LE Intermediate X1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[ cert data removed, it is the single cert.pem from lets encrypt, again ]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN = *.domain.tld

issuer=CN = Fake LE Intermediate X1

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1899 bytes and written 401 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

Comment: Re fun fact: LE uses one intermediate level, so `cat chain.pem cert.pem` is (imed,leaf). `openssl verify -CAfile root.pem somechain.pem` reads the first cert (imed) and verifies it against the root, which succeeds because imed is a direct child of the root. It does not verify or even read subsequent cert(s) (here leaf) in `somechain.pem`. Otherwise your logic looks right to me, although I don't use OpenLDAP and can't confirm. Exactly what do clients do wrong? Can you test with `openssl s_client [-starttls ldap]` as the client?

Comment: Thanks for claryfing how openssl verify actually works, my bad. I added logs as requested. Regarding what clients exactly do wrong: I would expect both of the connection tries above to succeed, not only the one where I provided the intermediate certificate on the client side along with the root certificate. The server is fed with a chain containing the intermediate certificate after all and should provide that one too, right?

Comment: For TLS in general the server should (per RFCs) send the chain optionally excluding root, i.e. in this case at least leaf and imed, and per your `s_client` output your server clearly doesn't. A client _may_ work around this by fetching imed themselves using the AIA extension, and it looks like some you tried did, but this is nonstandard. Since I don't use (or otherwise know) OpenLDAP I can't help on details of what it does, sorry.

Comment: Thanks again for your input @dave_thompson_085 . I've tried again feeding slapd with either (cert, imed) and (cert) with no difference from the client's perspective. The server sends the client cert only in both cases. I cross-checked with some other daemons I have running and these actually do send (cert, imed) if that is what was provided as their cert. So what this actually means is, that slapd simply can't be made to behave properly and feeding a bundle of (imed, root) to the clients is the only work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLDAP's `slapd` simply does not send the certificate chain to clients when TLS handshaking, even if a bundle of *server certificate, intermediate certificate* has been provided to it as its certificate.

The only suitable work-around without turning certificate validation off on the clients is the following.

- create a certificate bundle from *intermediate certificate, root certificate*
- make the client use this bundle as a trusted CA certificate, so it can factor the complete chain and validate; this works at least with software that's compiled against OpenLDAP libraries

  - OpenLDAP command line clients as `ldapmodify`, `ldapsearch`:
    add `TLS_CACERT imedrootbundle.pem` to either `~/.ldaprc` or the system-wide `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`
  - dovecot:
    add `tls_ca_cert_file = imedrootbundle.pem` to your `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext` file
  - postfix:
    add `tls_ca_cert_file = imedrootbundle.pem` to all of your `cf` files, that you use as postfix dictionaries to query your directory

Keep in mind though, that the root certificate is not provided by let's encrypt's certbot and may change in the future thus rendering your *intermediate certificate, root certificate* useless. I set up a hook script with certbot that checks the intermediate certificate's issuer and tries to select the correct root certificate based on those that I know of. It complains if it can't find one. This at least breaks everything in a controlled manner early in the process.

Answer (score 2):

As @Timor said:

> OpenLDAP's slapd simply does not send the certificate chain to clients when TLS handshaking, even if a bundle of server certificate, intermediate certificate has been provided to it as its certificate.

I had this problem when I was using `olcSyncrepl` to replicate a ldaps server with `tls_reqcert=demand` and slapd was generating `ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (-1)` error.

A simple workaround that I have found is to put intermediate certificate into a file (maybe `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in ubuntu) and put `tls_cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in the `olcSyncrepl`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've been using Let's Encrypt certificates with OpenLDAP, but for me it wasn't necessary to create a file containing a chain. I only have this from my certbot renew-hook script:

```bash
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/* /etc/ldap/ssl/
chown -R openldap:openldap /etc/ldap/ssl/
chmod 640 /etc/ldap/ssl/*
/etc/init.d/slapd force-reload >/dev/null
```

Comment: So you're saying that it just worked out of the box for you without adding either `TLS_REQCERT allow` or `TLS_CACERT ...` to client's `~/.ldaprc`/`/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` files when using LE staging certificates? If I may ask, which certificate file have you fed to slapd (value of `olcTLSCertificateFile` in `cn=config`)?

Comment: Sadly I don't have the LDAP configuration anymore. As far as I remember I only needed to configure `TLS_CACERTDIR`, `TLS_CERT` and `TLS_KEY`.